# multi stage gitlab matrix pipeline

Tags: c++, matrix, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I am working on a pipeline auto generate c++ conan packages, the matrix build below is based on the pipeline from this project https://github.com/aminya/setup-cpp.

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - os: ubuntu:20.04
        compiler: [llvm, gcc]
        build_type: [Debug, Release, MinSizeRel, RelWithDebInfo]
    variables:
      compiler: ${compiler}
      build_type: ${build_type}
    image: ${os}
    script:
      - *setup_linux
      - *setup_cpp
      - *build
```

the above works and creates 8 jobs that execute successfully.

What i would like is for each build to run a test step as a separate job like such

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - *test
    - -> if [${build_type} == "Debug"] *code_coverage
  artifact:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: /build/test/*xml
      cobertura: build/coverage.xml
```

is it possible for each build in the matrix build to follow on to an additional stage? do they all just get added as an additional script in the build stage?

```yaml
 script:
   - *setup_linux
   - *setup_cpp
   - *build
   - *test
   - *package
   - *upload
   - *etc....
```